# Neo4j Variable Length Relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j, using a graph of airports and their flights:

- Nodes with the label of Flight have the properties month and weekday.
- Nodes with the label of Airport have the property abbr (=abbreviation).
- A Flight has three relationships with An Airport: [:ORIGIN], [:DIVERTED_TO]*, [:DESTINATION], and in all cases the arrow points at the Airport.

(*shows the additional airports on the way of the flight.)

I need to show a visual route between JFK airport and SFO airport, which leaves on January 8th (Flight.month 1 and Flight.weekday 8) and must stop at DFW airport (it can stop in more airports).

This is the code which I've tried but didn't work for mr:

```
MATCH (f:Flight)-[:ORIGIN]->(j:Airport{abbr:'JFK'})
MATCH (s:Airport{abbr:'SFO'})<-[:DESTINATION]-(f)-[:DIVERTED_TO*1..5]->(d:Airport{abbr:'DFW'})
WHERE f.month=1 AND f.weekday=8
RETURN f,j,s,d
LIMIT 1
```

In case it might be helpful, there are more details about the fields [here](https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236&DB_Short_Name=On-Time).

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is your query working for you? What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't, there are no errors but it also doesn't show anything. I just wanted to share what I've tried so far to explain myself better.

Comment: Other than a few tweaks to improve readability and efficiency, your code should work -- as long as the data in your DB actually matches the query. Can you provide some code to generate sample data that will demonstrate the problem (or a visualization of such data)? Also, based on that data, what are the exact results that you are expecting?

Comment: For the last question: I basically need to prove I can find this specific flight. As for the code creating the graph itself wasn't something I've written myself: my university lecturer provided us with a file, which was based on the link I've included, so unfortunately there's not much else for me to show. Will a picture of a random Flight node and its relationship do? But thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Basically, we need to see examples of all 3 relationship types, including their end nodes. We need to verify the names of the node labels and relationship types, the directionality of the relationship types, and the properties of the nodes. If the DB has the [APOC](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/) plugin installed, the result of `CALL apoc.meta.schema()` would be ideal.